# JMeter: Is there a way to add expand and collapse feature to Jmeter HTML report for transaction controller

Tags: xslt, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am using transaction controllers which have few API calls under each of them. In the HTML report under the statistics columns i want to be able to expand each controller. On expanding controllers i should be able to see sub samples and their details.

Here is what i did: I unchecked the Generate parent sample. So all the api calls were shown under the statistics table in the report. But the order and grouping of calls under controllers went for a toss.

Is there a possiblility to add expand and collapse to each transaction controller and have the sub samples displayed under statistics table in the Jmeter HTML report?

This is how many report is right now : [image: Click here]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of JMeter 3.3 on 8th November 2017, No it’s not possible currently and would require an enhancement request:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

This may change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.